# Insert and alter data based on condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-update, case

I currently have Table1 that includes

```
 ID Gender
 1  m
 2  f
 3  f
 4  m
 5  f
 6  f
```

Now i am looking to insert this data into a second table (Table2). But basically i am trying to insert it with the words 'Male' and 'Female'.
So for example when Gender = 'm' in table 1 i want to insert the char 'Male' into the second table (table2) and the same for female.

I created some code such as

```
 UPDATE Table2
 SET 
 Gender =
 ( CASE WHEN Table1.Gender = 'm' THEN 'Male'
 WHEN Table1.Gender = 'f' THEN 'Female'
 ELSE 'N/a'
 END)
```

I have an SQL Fiddle schema if that is of any help -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a3080

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `INSERT` statement rather than `UPDATE` by Using `Case` expression  :

```
INSERT INTO table2
       SELECT id,
              CASE(Gender)
                  WHEN 'm'
                  THEN 'Male'
                  WHEN 'f'
                  THEN 'Female'
              END
       FROM table1;
```

**Result (table2):**

```
ID  Gender
1   Male
2   Female
3   Female
4   Male
5   Female
6   Female
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert rows into the second table, use `insert`, not `update`:

```
insert into table2(id, gender)
    select t1.id,
           (case when t1.gender = 'f' then 'female'
                 when t1.gender = 'm' then 'male'
            end) as gender_expanded
    from table1 t1;
```